# How to hide grey scrollbars on a DIV in Android - they only show when you cannot scroll

Tags: android, css, scrollbar, phonegap-build

I have a simple HTML/Jquery app compiled with Phonegap Build v3.1.0. I am using a DIV with `style="width:100%;overflow:scroll;"` to allow users to scroll content inside the DIV without scrolling the main page.

When the DIV's content is small (no scrolling possible) there are thin grey lines on the right and bottom edge of the DIV. They do not touch.  I am testing on a Nexus 7 running Android 4.4.2.

When the content inside is large enough, the bars disappear and the scrolling performs as expected.

**How can I remove the gray lines?** They overlap the content inside the DIV and ruin the appearance without being useful.

Note I am compiling with Phonegap Build online (not creating the .apk on my local machine with eclipse). All I can do is edit config.xml or my CSS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thankfully a friend pointed this out to me.

```
#whatever::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
```

It's annoying that the 'scrollbars' in question are no use whatsoever....

Comment: The scrollbars are good for usability as they give visual indication of the fact that you can scroll, and how far. HOWEVER - it's frustrating that they appear when the content is NOT long enough to scroll. Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Dude! f-yes! thank you for this, have been pulling my hair about why Chrome was adding scrollbars while i specifically had overflow:hidden for the past 3 hours, this resolved it. (used it minus the #whatever btw to apply it to every single thing, because f- Chrome thinking for me)

Comment: Use overflow:auto; to hide scrollbars when there is not enough content. Overflow:scroll will always show scrollbars, that's how it's supposed to work :)

Comment: Yeah, but REJH, you need overflow:scroll for momentum scrolling.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want the scrollbars to appear when the content is too long for the container use `overflow: auto`

For example if you have a div with content that you want to scroll only in y-direction use:

```
.class { overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto }
```