# Chrome Android—horizontal grey line

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-deployment

Chrome for Android
version 33.0.1750.136

A horizontal grey line is displaying *only* on the Chrome Android browser on my homepage.

I can remove this by setting the parent element (the div that houses the content) to `overflow: none;` but this affects the ajax content—unable to scroll horizontally.

The grey line doesn't show when there is more than one image in the content area.

Can anyone help with solving this issue? I appreciate your time!

[Horizontal Grey Line Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMXIi.jpg)

```
.content{
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.img-container{
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 auto;
height: auto;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
}

#img-home img{
height: 600px;
}


<div id ="pageContent" class="content"> // Used to load scrollable content—ajax
<div id="img-home" class="img-container"> // Creates area where images is placed
<img src="./images/00.png" title="main"  alt="main">
```

Comment: #whatever::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}

Here you go:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652848/how-to-hide-grey-scrollbars-on-a-div-in-android-they-only-show-when-you-cannot